# Multiline REGEX using VB Script

Tags: regex, text, vbscript

I have this text file that I need to check:

```
} else if ("saveAssured".equals(ACTION))         {
   Integer assuredNo = giisAssuredService.saveAssured(assured);
```

The pattern will include a variable:

```
var = "saveAssured"
reMethod.Pattern = """& var &""[.]equals\(ACTION\).{\n.\w+?.=.\w+?[.](\w+?)\(\w+?\)"
```

I need to capture the second 'saveAssured' from the text file. And the '\n' (new line) seems to be not working. Did I used it right? What other steps can I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html
>
> JavaScript and VBScript do not have an option to make the dot match
>   line break characters. In those languages, you can use a character
>   class such as `[\s\S]` to match any character. This character matches a
>   character that is either a whitespace character (including line break
>   characters), or a character that is not a whitespace character. Since
>   all characters are either whitespace or non-whitespace, this character
>   class matches any character.

And have a look at https://regex101.com/r/kH3aZ4/1 
Test is for JavaScript but since they have the same Regex flavor, that pattern will also work with VBScript.

```
Dim reMethod
Set reMethod = New RegExp
    reMethod.IgnoreCase = True
    reMethod.Pattern = """saveAssured""\.equals\(ACTION\)[\s\S]*?\{[\s\S]*?\.([^(]*)\("
```

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. Just got some logic errors in some part of my VBS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618032/regex-pattern-not-working-in-vb-script?noredirect=1#comment47386439_29618032.

Comment: Does VBScript not have the `MultiLine` property? - Ref [Regular Expression Programming (Scripting) - Section: Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ee236360%28v%3dvs.85%29)

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, there's a MultiLine property in VBScript's RegExp object but this question was about `dot matches newline` behavior and the `.Multiline` property does not supply that. `[\s\S]` instead `.` is the way to go with VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

The information around multiline in VBScript expressions is a bit inconsistent. The VBScript RegExp object does support them but the property is not well documented.

> <sup>*From [Regular Expression Programming (Scripting)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ee236360%28v%3dvs.85%29)*</sup>
>
> ---
>
> #### Flags
>
> In the JScript regular expression /abc/gim, the g specifies the global flag, the i specifies the ignore case flag, and the m specifies the multiline flag.
>
> In VBScript, you can specify these flags by setting the equivalent properties to True.
>
> The following table shows the allowed flags.
>
> ```
> JScript flag    VBScript property    If flag is present or property is True
>
> g               Global               Find all occurrences of the pattern in the searched string 
>                                      instead of just the first occurrence.
>
> i               IgnoreCase           The search is case-insensitive.
>
> m               Multiline            ^ matches positions following a \n or \r, and
>                                      $ matches positions before \n or \r.
>
>                                      Whether or not the flag is present or the property is True, 
>                                      ^ matches the position at the start of the searched string, 
>                                      and $ matches the position at the end of the searched string.
> ```

Below is an example of using `MultiLine`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim rx: Set rx = New RegExp
Dim matches, match
Dim data: data = Array("This is two lines of text", "This is the second line", "Another line")
Dim txt: txt = Join(data, vbCrLf)
With rx
  .Global= True
  .MultiLine = True
  .Pattern= "line$"
End With

Set matches = rx.Execute(txt)
WScript.Echo "Results:"
For Each match In matches
  WScript.Echo match.Value
Next
```

Output:

```
Results:
line
line
```

The difference with `MultiLine` set to `False`.

Output:

`Results:
line`