# Regex pattern not working in VB Script

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have this VBS code:

```
Option Explicit

   Dim reMethod, reInterface
    Dim vaction
    Dim fileService
    Dim mService
    Dim lineService
    Dim objFSO

    Const ForReading = 1

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set fileService = objFSO.OpenTextFile("GIISAssuredController.java" , ForReading) 

    Set reMethod = new regexp
    reMethod.Pattern = """\w+?""\.equals\(ACTION\)[\s\S]*?\{[\s\S]*?\.([^(]*)\("
    reMethod.IgnoreCase = True
    reMethod.Global = True

    Do Until fileService.AtEndOfStream
        lineService = fileService.ReadLine
        For Each mService In reMethod.Execute(lineService)
           vaction = mService.Submatches(0)
            Set reInterface = new regexp

            Wscript.Echo vaction

        Next
    Loop
```

And 'GIISAssuredController.java':

```
} else if ("hello".equals(ACTION))         {
   Integer assuredNo = giisAssuredService.saveAssured(assured);
```

The regex pattern is not working.

I am expecting the output to be is:

```
saveAssured
```

But instead, it's not echoing anything. I tried the regex pattern here > https://regex101.com/r/kH3aZ4/1, and it's getting the 'saveAssured' string.

This question is related to: [Multiline REGEX using VB Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364294/multiline-regex-using-vb-script/29366438#29366438)

Comment: How is it "not working"? What actual results are you seeing? Are there any errors?

Comment: It doesn't echo anything. I included additional details on the question.

Comment: you use `ForReading` before setting its value ?

Comment: I used `ForReading` at `fileService`.

Comment: and you set its value in the next line, so when you use it at `fileService` it still has no value..

Comment: Thanks, I didn't noticed it. I already transferred it but it's still not working.

Comment: This will never work as it is written. You are reading the input file line by line but you are trying to match a pattern that spawns over two lines. Read the full file and then apply the regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the expression needs to match a text that spawns over multiple lines, but you read the file line by line and test line by line, there will never be a match.

```
Option Explicit

    Const ForReading = 1

Dim code
    code = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject" _ 
           ).OpenTextFile("GIISAssuredController.java" , ForReading _ 
           ).ReadAll() 

Dim mService

    With new RegExp 
        .Pattern = """\w+?""\.equals\(ACTION\)[\s\S]*?\{[\s\S]*?\.([^(]*)\("
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        For Each mService in .Execute(code)
            WScript.Echo mService.Submatches(0)
        Next 
    End With
```