# Vbscript Regular expression for multiline text?

Tags: regex, vbscript

```
"value:=This customer has one or more active tax exemptions available\.
\n
 \n
Do you want to apply a tax exemption to this transaction\?"
```

I tried regular expression like `"Value:=This.*"` but it is not identifying entire text. Please tell me how can i identify entire text using VbScript regular expression by validating only first word in the entire text. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean something like this ? [Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/5DQeQr/1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline REGEX using VB Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364294/multiline-regex-using-vb-script)

Comment: Use `.MultiLine = True` on your `RegExp` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression)

For example:

```
Dim s : s = "value:=This customer has one or more active tax exemptions available." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to apply a tax exemption to this transaction?"
With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "^value:=This(.|\n|\r)*"
    With .Execute(s)
        WScript.Echo .Item(0).Value
    End With
End With
```

...whose `.Pattern` starts with (^) '**value:=This**', followed by any character (.), line feed (aka, newline) (\n), or carriage return (\r) repeated zero or more times (*).

Output:

```
value:=This customer has one or more active tax exemptions available.

Do you want to apply a tax exemption to this transaction?
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just use `.MultiLine = True`. Ref [Multiline REGEX using VB Script](//stackoverflow.com/a/58816556)

Answer (score 0):

I guess,

```
value:=This\b[\s\S]*
```

might work OK.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ2158/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xZ2158/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/xZ2158/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what i'm looking for.